# Hard to steer when really cold - ~20 to 30 degrees

Tags: toyota, power-steering, sienna

Its a 2004 Toyota Sienna van 6 cyl in great condition. Belt is not loose and the fluid is full. When it warms up it's, about great 15 minutes. I'm guessing the pump. However, I do have a seized tie rod, so I was told recently when I got 2 new front tires.  Is it safe to drive?

Comment: My MB E-class has 98k miles, fresh power steering fluid, and belt. At cold start (~15-25) degrees, its steering is heavier and it grunts back at me first thing in the morning. Not an answer, just empathizing. I guess the shop meant they could not adjust your tie rod when they say it was seized. If so, that won't affect your power steering. At any rate, you're safe. Power steering pumps are mainly for low speed maneuvering and won't prevent you from getting home.

Comment: Were you planning on fixing it yourself or just trying to understand the problem?

Comment: What does the PS fluid look like? Is it clear or gunky?

Comment: Is your question about the tie rod or the power steering?

Answer (score 4):

Safe to drive, probably, but it might be hard on your new tires.

Seized tie rod may mean only that they were unable to adjust the position of the stop nut and/or outer tie rod end on the threaded shaft of the inner tie rod end. This adjustment is necessary to complete a front-end or 4-wheel alignment.

However since you said it was hard to steer, it might be missing lubrication on the inner tie rod end joints, which are ball joints (but not the ball joints that hold up your vehicle's weight). This condition will get worse until significant play is present in your steering, and will need to be addressed soon.